# (VB.NET) Is There a Way to "lock" a Windows Folder and its Contents?

Tags: windows, vb.net, file, directory

I want to have my VB.NET program secure folder(s) which all contain a handful of different files so the files within cannot be edited unless the program "unlocks" the folder in Windows. Is this possible? I do not want the folder/files hidden just essentially in some Read-Only state or something or fake out windows into thinking they are already open. The goal is if someone opens the files without the program "unlocking" them, they cannot edit/save changes.

Comment: Does the editing take place within _your_ application? Or does your application launch the associated application? E.g. launch Excel for *,xlsx files in the folder.

Comment: Is "unlock" a one-way trip, or is the folder supposed to become locked again?  What is supposed to happen to program that have open handles to protected files when the folder transitions back to locked?  It is very doubtful that you will be able to do this using pure .NET --- existing "secure folder" solutions install kernel-mode drivers to intercept access.  However if it's ok to leave existing handles open, then you can do something by editing ACLs.

Comment: My application does not open/use the folders or files, it will just manage it. I want to be able to open my program and select a folder and "lock" it as well as "unlock" it. But I need the files to stay "locked" in a read only or such state even after the application is closed. One would then use the application to change the state if needed. But I do not want the files hidden. I still need transparency that they exist.

Comment: The scope of the project is to lock files to manage revisions like a "Vault" program but the amount of files we want to manage is small compared to the cost of such a program that can sign in and sign out a file. I am not looking to "Lock" a file in the sense it is unreadable or hidden; just to prevent people from making edits. I very much so need the files intact and viewable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my surprise just making the file/folder have the Read Only attribute solves my problem exactly how I wanted. Sample code to make a file or folder Read Only is below:

```
Dim LockFolder As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c ATTRIB +R " + """" + Application.StartupPath() + "\" + SelectedNodeText + """\* /S /D") _
   With {.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, .Verb = "runas"}
Process.Start(LockFolder)
'===== FILE LOCK:
Dim LockFile As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c ATTRIB +R " + """" + Application.StartupPath() + "\" + SelectedNodeText + """") _
   With {.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, .Verb = "runas"}
Process.Start(LockFile)
```

`Application.StartupPath` is the first half of my path and the `SelectedNodeText` is the actual file name which complete the CMD command. The rest is just to make the command run as Admin and not have a popup command window.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to achieve this functionality is to create a Kernel Minifilter file system driver that prevents other apps from writing or even reading files specified by your program, however, driver development needs extensive knowledge of the system Kernel.

**Filter Manager Concepts**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/filter-manager-concepts

**Processing I/O Operations**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/processing-i-o-operations

**Communication Between User Mode and Kernel Mode**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/communication-between-user-mode-and-kernel-mode

**Writing Preoperation Callback Routines**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/writing-preoperation-callback-routines

**Completing an I/O Operation in a Preoperation Callback Routine**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/completing-an-i-o-operation-in-a-preoperation-callback-routine